# Differentiating back/forward navigation with backbone.js routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a simple router setup here:

```
class Router extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '/a': 'a'
    '/b': 'b'

  a: -> alert 'a'
  b: -> alert 'b'

app = new Router()
app.navigate '/a'
Backbone.history.start()
```

Code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tH2eW/

In use where you can see the hash url change:
http://jsfiddle.net/tH2eW/show/

This works, it runs code when the hash changes.  But how do I know if it was a forward (clicked a link to load a new page) or if it was a back button press?  I want to animate things slightly differently if we are going back to a previous screen.

Do hash based URLs support this differentiation at all?

Comment: Don't have a good answer for you, but could you bind to hashchange/onpopstate to track your own history stack and compare current url to the stack?

Answer (score 0):

We ended doing something I'm not too happy about.  We encode the page depth in the url.

```
foo.html#!1/index
foo.html#!2/detail/123
```

Then we can easily see if that number is going up or down and animate accordingly.  It works, but elegant it is not.